# Proving the convergence of $\;\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(4n)}{\ln(n) + \ln(\ln(n))}\;.$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Proving the convergence of a series

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(4n)}{\ln(n) + \ln(\ln(n))}\;.$$

I tried Abel's test, but what to do with these logarithms is not clear. Take the exponential function of the fraction. In general, it is not clear. Please help.

Comment: $n=1$ makes the denominator $0 + \ln (0)$. Is this an error?

Comment: exactly, a typo

Answer (score 1):

Let, for $ n>1,$

$$a_n=\sin(4n)$$
$$c_n=\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))$$
and
$$b_n=\frac{1}{c_n}$$

the partial sums sequence $(\sum_{k=2}^na_k) $ is known to be bounded.

The sequence $ (c_n) $ is clearly increasing with $\lim_{n\to+\infty}c_n=+\infty$
thus

$(b_n)$ is decreasing to zero.

By Abel's Rule, called also Dirichlet's test, we conclude the convergence of
$$\sum a_nb_n$$